# Unable to ping through router switch router

Tags: router, switch

[image][image][image]## **Question**

- Why in firewall_2 routing table rip address is not showing like router_b?
  As I done Rip routing In Firewall_2 as shown in the right side image

#### rip:

- `192.168.1.0`
- `192.168.2.0`
- `209.165.200.0`

#### Screenshots

- Here is a [Dia[image]gram][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RZvB.png) of the network/situation,

Comment: Hello Sadia! welcome to serverfault ! please, if you haven't already, check https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask - (it provides a good base of what to include in a question, such as `output` of any `command`, error messages from any `application`, or any network dump(non sensitive) and info such as OS, hardware, and **why you can't** - that is, are you connected?, is it firewall? (..) include more context and what you have tried(even if it didn't work) :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.Please  check the image I have attached..For ping from  pc_b to firewall_1 (in image ) what else settings i need to do!? As i given all ip address and Add rip routing.

Comment: In the most basic setups like this one the accessibility issue is caused by either 1) routing issues, 2) access/firewalling issues. It appears the drawing is from Cisco Packet Tracer. This application has reachability tool, where you can simulate the packet and step by step trace if from the source to the destination. Do that, see where it gets you. Each step it will tell you what is to be checked - arp tables, routing tables, access lists etc. Also make sure the subnet masks are correct, the images doesn't contain that. +which interface you are trying to reach on the firewall 0/0 or 0/1?

Comment: @SadiaTamanna no worries; I checked it, but what is the output you get from the ping? I mean, if you ping it, can you include at least the output of the ping command? (or is this a question, like - theory? if that's the case, add that to the question)   and, what OS is running on them? e.g linux or windows?

Comment: just to clarify what I mean with my re-asking - in your case, it doesn't ping - so how doesn't it? like, does the command or tool just wait(i.e no response) or does it get some output but not "correct" ?  anything like this - command, tool, output, any error message, include it to the question - this is what I meant :),  and add tags if the tool is a tag, e.g Wireshark (if you used that) (for example)

Comment: @William_Martens  please have a view.I have added image of ping command from pc_b to firewall_1. I am unable to attach the pkt file.May be through email it could be sent.

Comment: @SadiaTamanna did you try that troubleshooting tool inside CPT?

Comment: @SadiaTamanna + did you check the router_b has the route to 209.x.x.x and the firewall_1 has the route 192.168.2.0 network?

Comment: @jabbson yes..Please check recent image i have add.There i add rip routing

Comment: if you would like to upload the file I might take a look

Comment: can you provide your mail.here file upload option is not showing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139772/discussion-between-sadia-tamanna-and-jabbson).

Comment: I am in the chat if you are available, or just upload the file to one of the public file upload services and provide the link

Comment: Please never change the question for any reason, especially after some answers were provided. This brings the value of the question down as nobody can benefit from answers if the question was changed. If you have additional questions, just create a new one or update an existing one by adding an additional question on the bottom.

Comment: @jabbson Sorry ..I will keep that mind.Would you please check this link.Now i am facing this prob..please help me to figure it out

https://serverfault.com/questions/1112798/want-to-try-to-block-a-particular-ip-address